# Taking mean of a numerical function $f(t',x,y)$

Tags: differential-equations, probability-or-statistics

$f(t,x,y)$ is a solution from NDSolve, in a domain $\mathcal{D}$.

If $f(t,x,y)$ was an analytical func I would

$$\overline{f(t)}=\frac{  \int _{\mathcal{D}} f(t,x,y) dx dy}{\mathcal{D}}$$

Since $f(t,x,y)$ is number for each x point, how can one compute its average value in the domain  for a certain $t=t'$? It is basically taking the mean of $f(t',x,y)$ in the domain but I couldn't figure out how to do it.

The question might be too simple or trivial to answer, but googled it and look around here and couldn't find any clue on how. Maybe I don't know the correct keywords etc.

Comment: You can use `NIntegrate` to perform the integral and `RegionMeasure` to compute the surface area of your integration region.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need first to define your region; call it `reg`. Then, `f[t', x, y]` for a fixed `t'` is simply a function of x and y. To get the mean, you may either use `Integrate` or `NIntegrate`:

```
Integrate[f[x, y] , {x, y} ∈ reg]  / Integrate[1 , {x, y} ∈ reg]
```